# How can memory leak be avoided when TRttiProperty.SetValue is used with TMemoryStream property?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I use `SourceProperties[0].SetValue(lObject, lStream)` to set the `MemoryStream : TMemoryStream` property of `lObject`.

If I subsequently free the `lStream`, the `MemoryStream` property of `lObject` appears to be set to `nil`.

If I don't free the `lStream`, I get a memory leak.

What would be the correct approach to assign an `lStream` to the `MemoryStream` property via RTTI?

Full example code listed below:

```pascal
unit Unit28;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Rtti;

type
  TMyObject = Class(TObject)
  private
    pMemoryStream : TMemoryStream;
  published
    property MemoryStream : TMemoryStream read pMemoryStream  write pMemoryStream;
    constructor Create;
    destructor  Destroy;override;
  end;

type
  TForm28 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form28: TForm28;

implementation


{$R *.fmx}

constructor TMyObject.Create;
begin
  pMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

destructor TMyObject.Destroy;
begin
  pMemoryStream.DisposeOf;
  inherited;
end;


////Problematic when using RTTI
procedure TForm28.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourceRttiContext : TRttiContext;
  SourceRttiType : TRttiType;
  SourceProperties: TArray<TRttiProperty>;
  lStream : TMemoryStream;
  lObject : TObject;
begin
  lObject := TMyObject.Create;
  SourceRttiType := SourceRttiContext.GetType(lObject.ClassType);
  SourceProperties := SourceRttiType.GetProperties;
  lStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  lStream.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg');
  if (SourceProperties[0].PropertyType.ToString = 'TMemoryStream') then
  begin
    SourceProperties[0].SetValue(lObject, lStream);
  end;
  lStream.DisposeOf;
  TMyObject(lObject).MemoryStream.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Test1.jpg');
  lObject.DisposeOf;
end;


////No problems when not using RTTI
procedure TForm28.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lStream : TMemoryStream;
  lObject : TMyObject;
begin
  lObject := TMyObject.Create;
  lStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  lStream.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg');
  lObject.MemoryStream.LoadFromStream(lStream);
  lStream.DisposeOf;
  lObject.MemoryStream.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Test1.jpg');
  lObject.DisposeOf;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You not only have a leak, you are also working with dead memory stream object.

Problem is that when you set `MemoryStream` property you are directly setting its reference to point to locally created `lStream` object. You are not creating a copy, and therefore you are leaking memory stream instance created in `TMyObject` constructor.

I am not sure what is the purpose of using RTTI in your example, and optimal solution depends on what you are trying to achieve, which is not absolutely clear.

If you need to set stream through RTTI then you need to implement property setter in order to avoid leaks.

```
  TMyObject = Class(TObject)
  private
    pMemoryStream : TMemoryStream;
    procedure SetMemoryStream(const Value: TMemoryStream);
  published
    property MemoryStream: TMemoryStream read pMemoryStream write SetMemoryStream;
    constructor Create;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  end;

procedure TMyObject.SetMemoryStream(const Value: TMemoryStream);
begin
  pMemoryStream.CopyFrom(Value, 0);
end;

var
  SourceRttiContext : TRttiContext;
  SourceRttiType : TRttiType;
  SourceProperties: TArray<TRttiProperty>;
  lStream : TMemoryStream;
  lObject : TObject;
begin
  lObject := TMyObject.Create;
  try
    SourceRttiType := SourceRttiContext.GetType(lObject.ClassType);
    SourceProperties := SourceRttiType.GetProperties;
    lStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      lStream.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg');
      if (SourceProperties[0].PropertyType.ToString = 'TMemoryStream') then
      begin
        SourceProperties[0].SetValue(lObject, lStream);
      end;
      TMyObject(lObject).MemoryStream.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Test1.jpg');
    finally
      lStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lObject.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, creating a copy will use more memory. To avoid that, one of the solutions would be to transfer ownership of locally created stream to `TMyObject`. In that case you should not release `lStream` locally. Since ownership transfer complicates exception handling the easiest way to handle double free it is to set `lStream` to `nil` after transfer is completed and `TMyObject` instance will be responsible for releasing memory stream.

```
procedure TMyObject.SetMemoryStream(const Value: TMemoryStream);
begin
  pMemoryStream.Free;
  pMemoryStream := Value;
end;

var
  SourceRttiContext : TRttiContext;
  SourceRttiType : TRttiType;
  SourceProperties: TArray<TRttiProperty>;
  lStream : TMemoryStream;
  lObject : TObject;
begin
  lObject := TMyObject.Create;
  try
    SourceRttiType := SourceRttiContext.GetType(lObject.ClassType);
    SourceProperties := SourceRttiType.GetProperties;
    lStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      lStream.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg');
      if (SourceProperties[0].PropertyType.ToString = 'TMemoryStream') then
        begin
          SourceProperties[0].SetValue(lObject, lStream);
          // ownership transfer is successful nil local reference to
          // avoid double free
          lStream := nil;
        end;
      TMyObject(lObject).MemoryStream.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Test1.jpg');
    finally
      lStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lObject.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But the main question here remains why are you using locally created memory stream in the first place, instead of loading image directly with `TMyObject` memory stream instance?

Comment: The image loading/saving was only example code to illustrate the problem.   TMemoryStream.CopyFrom seems to expect two arguments, but there is only one in your property setter?

Comment: Other arguments in CopyFrom are optional and if you don't pass it default value will be used. In this case 0, and that will alter CopyFrom behavior to set Source stream position to 0 and copy the whole stream.

Comment: My compiler (Berlin 10.1) expects a 2nd argument.  I have used pMemoryStream.CopyFrom(Value, 0) and that works 100%.

Comment: I edited the answer to include explicit parameter for anyone using older versions.

Answer (score 1):

When using RTTI, you change the property MemoryStream to point to a newly created local memory stream previously loaded from a file.

When not using RTTI, you get the property memory stream and call LoadFromStream to load it with the local stream.

The two methods are obviously different!

There are several ways to solve that.

One is to change the way you act with RTTI: instead of SetValue, use GetValue to get the instance of the memory stream just like you do without using RTTI and then call LoadFromStream.

Another one is to add a setter for the MemoryStream property. When called, it uses LoadFromStream to load the "internal" memory stream.